# $scope is undefined in angular js app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<html ng-app="myBlog">
    <head>
<!--        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
 -->    <script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/libs/angular.min.js' %}"></script>
<!--        <script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/modules/app.module.js' %}"></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/modules/app.config.js' %}"></script> -->
<!--        <script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/modules/blog-list.module.js' %}"></script>
 -->        <script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/controllers/blog-list.js' %}"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name">
        <p>hi , {{name}}</p>

        <div ng-controller="Controller">
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
            <button ng-click="someTest()">click</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is the controller

```
'use strict'

var blogList = angular.module('myBlog' , []);

blogList.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope){

        $scope.clicks="";

        console.log("he");
        $scope.title = 'Hi there';
        $scope.clicks = 0;
        console.log($scope)

        $scope.someTest = function(){
            console.log($scope)
            console.log("there")
            $scope.clicks +=1;
            $scope.title = 'Clicked' + clicks;
        };
}]);
```

When the button is clicked it gives the error

> angular.min.js:118 ReferenceError: clicks is not defined at
>   b.$scope.someTest (blog-list.js:16) at fn (eval at compile
>   (angular.min.js:233), :4:215) at b (angular.min.js:126) at
>   e (angular.min.js:276) at b.$eval (angular.min.js:145) at b.$apply
>   (angular.min.js:146) at HTMLButtonElement.
>   (angular.min.js:276) at Sf (angular.min.js:37) at HTMLButtonElement.d
>   (angular.min.js:37)

How can i get rid of the error ..thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `$scope.title = 'Clicked' + clicks;`.You missed to refer to the `$scope` when you have used the `clicks`. Change it to `$scope.title = 'Clicked' + $scope.clicks;` So says your error:

> ReferenceError: clicks is not defined at b.$scope.someTest

```
$scope.someTest = function(){
     console.log($scope);
     console.log("there");
     $scope.clicks += 1;
     $scope.title = 'Clicked' + $scope.clicks;
};
```

Comment: @payalarora Have you changed `clicks` to `$scope.clicks` ?

Comment: yes that thing is working now..but it doesnt show on index.html when accessing using {{title}}

Comment: I can't say. I don't see all your code. Try to debug your code

Comment: the h1 tags are empty where i am using {{title}}

Answer (score 0):

It seem to not define variable "clicks"

$scope.title = 'Clicked' + clicks;  <--- It should be "$scope.clicks" right ?